Reviewing nested dictionaries in Python
I have a nested dictionary inside another dictionary with a key value of a date.
The value of the dictionary (inside the dictionary) is a list of 6 numbers.
How do I access the individual numbers of the list? I've included for you below how I formed my dictionary.
dictsee = {"dicto_{}".format(i): {'Date': dates[i], 'nums' : crapola[0+(6*i): 6+(6*i)]} for i in range(arb)}

for key, value in dictsee.items():
    print(f"{key} numbers were {value}.")


iiuc value['nums'][x] where x is the index you want to access

Right  dictsee['dicto_1'] is a dictionary just like any other dictionary.  dictsee['dicto_1']['Date'] is a list like any other list.  It's just spelled funny.

dictsee["dicto_5"]["nums"][0]

Try: [f"{k}: {el}" for k, v in dictsee.items() for el in v['nums']].

@JohnGordon thank you for your help! I appreciate all the answers, but John's got right to what I needed to do. Thank you John, and thank you everyone!
